# Insert in database in bulk django

Tags: python-3.x

I've a model with 3 fields : packing_id, multiplier, cost_id. I've data for 
packing_id and multiplier in arrays

```
packing_id = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
multiplier = ['11', '21', '31', '41']
```

and cost_id will be same for these 4 entries.
Database should look like:

```
packing_id       multiplier   cost_id
1                  11           1
----------------|-----------|-------
2                  21           1
----------------|-----------|-------
3                  31           1
----------------|-----------|-------
4                  41           1
----------------|-----------|-------
```

How can i insert in in Sqlite database in bulk without using for loop

Answer (score 1):

Check Django's `bulk_create` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create
And use some `zip` magic https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip

```
packing_id = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
multiplier = ['11', '21', '31', '41']
cost_id = [1, 1, 1, 1]
all_columns = zip(packing_id, multiplier, cost_id)

YourModel.objects.bulk_create([
    YourModel(
        packing_id=packing_id,
        multiplier=multiplier,
        cost_id=cost_id,
    )
    for packing_id, multiplier, cost_id in all_columns
])
```